# How to join and use a database first view with TypeORM

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

So like the title says, I'm trying to use TypeORM to consume a view that has already been created, and to use that view as part of a join where the joining column is an FK for two different tables.

So far from what I've been able to piece together from the documentation this isn't possible, and that views can only be used code first, but this just seems wrong.

What I have is 4 entities: hwcr_complaint, complaint_identifier, geo_organization_unit_code, and cos_geo_org_unit where cos_geo_org_unit is my view.

```
//-- top level entity
@Entity()
@Unique(["complaint_identifier"])
export class HwcrComplaint
{
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
      hwcr_complaint_guid: UUID;
    
      @OneToOne(() => Complaint)
      @JoinColumn({name: "complaint_identifier"})
      complaint_identifier: Complaint;
    
      @Column({length: 32})
      create_user_id: string;
    
      @Column({type: "uuid"})
      create_user_guid: UUID;
    
      @Column()
      create_timestamp: Date;
    
      @Column({length: 32})
      update_user_id: string;

      @Column({type: "uuid"})
      update_user_guid: UUID;
    
      @Column()
      update_timestamp: Date;
   
      constructor(complaint_identifier?: Complaint, 
        create_user_id?: string, create_user_guid?: UUID, create_timestamp?: Date, update_user_id?: string, update_user_guid?: UUID, update_timestamp?: Date) {
        this.complaint_identifier = complaint_identifier;
        this.create_user_id = create_user_id;
        this.create_user_guid = create_user_guid;
        this.create_timestamp = create_timestamp;
        this.update_user_id = update_user_id;
        this.update_user_guid = update_user_guid;
        this.update_timestamp = update_timestamp;
      }
}

//-- complaint
@Entity()
export class Complaint {
  @PrimaryColumn({ length: 20 })
  complaint_identifier: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => GeoOrganizationUnitCode)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "geo_organization_unit_code" })
  geo_organization_unit_code: GeoOrganizationUnitCode;

  @OneToOne(() => CosGeoOrgUnit)                       ///--
  @JoinColumn({ name: "geo_organization_unit_code" })  ///-- this is what I'm trying to join
  cos_geo_org_unit: CosGeoOrgUnit;                     ///--

  @Column({ length: 4000, nullable: true })
  detail_text: string;

  @Column({ length: 120, nullable: true })
  caller_name: string;

  @Column({ length: 120, nullable: true })
  caller_address: string;

  @Column({ length: 120, nullable: true })
  caller_email: string;

  @Column({ length: 15, nullable: true })
  caller_phone_1: string;

  @Column({ length: 32 })
  create_user_id: string;

  @Column({ type: "uuid" })
  create_user_guid: UUID;

  @Column()
  create_timestamp: Date;

  @Column({ length: 32 })
  update_user_id: string;

  @Column({ type: "uuid" })
  update_user_guid: UUID;

  @Column()
  update_timestamp: Date;

  constructor(
    detail_text?: string,
    caller_name?: string,
    caller_address?: string,
    caller_email?: string,
    caller_phone_1?: string,
    create_user_id?: string,
    create_user_guid?: UUID,
    create_timestamp?: Date,
    update_user_id?: string,
    update_user_guid?: UUID,
    update_timestamp?: Date,
    geo_organization_unit_code?: GeoOrganizationUnitCode,
    cos_geo_org_unit?: CosGeoOrgUnit,
    complaint_identifier: string
  ) {
    this.detail_text = detail_text;
    this.caller_name = caller_name;
    this.caller_address = caller_address;
    this.caller_email = caller_email;
    this.caller_phone_1 = caller_phone_1;
    this.create_user_id = create_user_id;
    this.create_user_guid = create_user_guid;
    this.create_timestamp = create_timestamp;
    this.update_user_id = update_user_id;
    this.update_user_guid = update_user_guid;
    this.update_timestamp = update_timestamp;
    this.complaint_identifier = complaint_identifier;

    this.geo_organization_unit_code = geo_organization_unit_code;
    this.cos_geo_org_unit = cos_geo_org_unit;
  }
}

//-- geo_org_unit_type_code
@Entity()
export class GeoOrgUnitTypeCode 
{
      @PrimaryColumn({length: 10})
      geo_org_unit_type_code: string;

      @Column({length: 50})
      short_description: string;
    
      @Column({length: 250, nullable: true })
      long_description: string;

      @Column()
      display_order: number;

      @Column()
      active_ind: boolean;
    
      @Column({length: 32})
      create_user_id: string;
    
      @Column({type: "uuid"})
      create_user_guid: UUID;
    
      @Column()
      create_timestamp: Date;

      @Column({length: 32})
      update_user_id: string;
    
      @Column({type: "uuid"})
      update_user_guid: UUID;
    
      @Column()
      update_timestamp: Date;
    
      constructor(geo_org_unit_type_code?: string) {
        this.geo_org_unit_type_code = geo_org_unit_type_code;
      }
}

//-- cos_geo_org_unit

@ViewEntity({
  name: "cos_geo_org_unit",
  expression: `select * from cos_geo_org_unit_flat_vw`,
})
export class CosGeoOrgUnit {
  @ViewColumn()
  area_code: string;

  @ViewColumn()
  area_name: string;

  @ViewColumn()
  region_code: string;

  @ViewColumn()
  region_name: string;

  @ViewColumn()
  zone_code: string;

  @ViewColumn()
  zone_name: string;

  @ViewColumn({name: "offloc_code"})
  office_location_code: string;

  @ViewColumn({name: "offloc_name"})
  office_location_name: string;
}
```

What we're trying to do is select a `hwcr_complaint`, but that complaint needs join `complaint_identifier`, and the data for `complaint_identifier` also needs to join up `geo_org_unit_type_code` and `cos_geo_org_unit`

in the complaint entity I've got the following defined:

```
  @ManyToOne(() => GeoOrganizationUnitCode)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "geo_organization_unit_code" })
  geo_organization_unit_code: GeoOrganizationUnitCode;

  @OneToOne(() => CosGeoOrgUnit)                       ///--
  @JoinColumn({ name: "geo_organization_unit_code" })  ///-- this is what I'm trying to join
  cos_geo_org_unit: CosGeoOrgUnit;                     ///--
```

the first join works as expected, but the second join won't work when I try to query it in a service

```
    return this.hwcrComplaintsRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("hwcr_complaint")
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "hwcr_complaint.complaint_identifier",
      "complaint_identifier"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect("hwcr_complaint.species_code", "species_code")
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "hwcr_complaint.hwcr_complaint_nature_code",
      "hwcr_complaint_nature_code"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "hwcr_complaint.attractant_hwcr_xref",
      "attractant_hwcr_xref"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "complaint_identifier.complaint_status_code",
      "complaint_status_code"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "complaint_identifier.referred_by_agency_code",
      "referred_by_agency_code"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "complaint_identifier.owned_by_agency_code",
      "owned_by_agency_code"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "complaint_identifier.geo_organization_unit_code",
      "geo_organization_unit_code"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "complaint_identifier.cos_geo_org_unit",
      "area_code"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      "attractant_hwcr_xref.attractant_code",
      "attractant_code"
    )
    .getOne()
  }
```

If I try and look at the raw sql thats generated, it doesn't even try to include the join to the view.

At this point I'm really struggling and any help figuring this out, or if we need to switch to a different orm would be great